# Firebase Storage - how to authorize file download?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

When using Firebase Storage, you set security rules for authorization to get the url of a file, for example using `getDownloadURL()`. But, once a user has that URL, what's stopping hackers from crowd-sourcing the URL?

I know in Google Cloud Storage, you can use signed urls, which is time limited (still not doing real authorization). But I don't see any mention of a `getSignedURL` in the [Firebase Storage documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl). I've seen it on articles about Firebase Storage but never in Firebase's documentation directly.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do real user authorization for accessing Firebase Storage files. Please tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, once a user has that URL, what's stopping hackers from crowd-sourcing the URL?

Nothing. In fact, that's precisely the point of a download URL: it gives anyone who has the URL read-only access to the data.

If you want to only grant specific users access to the file, don't generate a download URL but instead use the SDK to access the data, and [use security rules to control that access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security).

---

Since you clarified that you're asking about web apps: until late 2021 in the JavaScript/Web SDK using a download URL is the only way to get at the data. Since JavaScript SDK version 9,5, the JavaScript SDKs also have `getBlock()`, `getBytes()` and `getStream()` methods, which *are* enforced through security rules.

Comment: Hi Puf, thanks for answering this. Okay great, I won't generate a download URL. However, I don't see in the documentation any other ways to access the files.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were asking for a web app. There indeed a download URL is the only way to get at the data, while for the native mobile SDKs we also have `getData()` and `getFile()` methods. I know adding such methods for web clients was considered, so it might be worth [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). Until that time, if signed URLs fit your needs better, you can use those. Both signed URLs and download URLs are just URLs that provide read-only access to the data. Signed URLs just expire, while download URLs don't.

Comment: Thank you, I made a feature request and suggested this caveat be noted in the documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @MarcusGallegos Anything else needed here?

Comment: Update: Firebase Javscript SDK version 9.5 (November 18, 2021) added `getBlob` `getBytes` `getStream` https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_directly_from_the_sdk https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_950_-_november_18_2021

Comment: Good point @AnisAbboud!  I updated my answer with that info and those methods.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the above comments, the web library does not contain any method to access the document with the security rules. If they add this feature, I'll update this answer!