# Cloud Storage - Disabled Public Access Prevention, but Failed

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, cloud, firebase-storage

Okay, I was using Flutter and Firebase to upload data into Cloud Storage. I gained the downloadURL which can be accessible on web if people know the URL. I had enabled Public Access Prevention in Google Cloud Storage Console based on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-public-access-prevention) and chose Access Control Uniform for this on [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/).

I also had added Security Rule in Firebase Cloud Storage, so only Users with certain custom token can use it. But, it seems useless as everyone can get its downloaded URL. My question is why is that I still able to access the file if I am using the same URL which was I stored in Firestore? You can test it on this [url](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/felix-had.appspot.com/o/music%2FEpic%2F03.%20Ancestors.output.mp3?alt=media&token=6f8a141b-39f0-4f15-af5f-9021b55a6e3e).

Can hacker get the download URL I downloaded from Firestore?
Is there a secure way to download song from Firebase Cloud Storage so hacker won't get its URL?

Thank you for helping me out.

Updated v2:
I just found out that current audio file has its own AuthenticatedUrl as shown on this picture below. How can I get access to this url?

[image: Authenticated URL]

Updated v1:

I think I haven't activated Firebase App Check. Does this feature have ability to prevent it from being accessed publicly or maybe there is other things that I have to do to be able to prevent it being accessed publicly, beside all ways I described above???

[image: Cloud Security Rules]

[image: Shown it's not public]

[image: Image on Google Cloud Storage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules only check if a user can get the download URL and do not restrict anyone from using it. You can use the [`getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files#doSwnload_in_memory) method instead. It doesn't return any URL and **downloads the files directly and is controlled by security rules**. So a user must be authenticated to fetch them.

Comment: Uhm... What I meant is how to prevent hacker accessing the url generated from Flutter? Since the getDownloadUrl() has the same url which is stored inside Cloud Storage. I found out on the Google Cloud Console, the current audio file has AuthenticatedURL which is cannot be downloadable if it is not authenticated.... You can try using this url to try it: https://storage.cloud.google.com/felix-had.appspot.com/music/Relax/02.%20Rivers.output.mp3

Comment: Can you read the last update on question? I wanna know how to get the AuthenticatedUrl from Cloud Storage Console.

Comment: @Wege  open any object and your should see  define "hacker"? Like a person would need access to a user's Firebase Auth Account and then only they can get the URL/file at first place. If someone just bruteforces the URL (that is unlikely). Yes that auth URL will require you to be authenticated with Google.

Comment: If you just use `getData()` then you don't have to deal with the URLs at first and get into GCP console.

Comment: But using getData() will force user to download all the songs, and it will make the app consumes a total of 20 GBs.... I really a workaround about this use case. If you know, that will be helpful.

Comment: @Wege where did you read that? Have you checked the documentation linked in my answer? It only fetches the file that your StorageReference points to..

Comment: Yeah, I have read it. But my app derived all songs from one single category in Firestore, and it needs a downloadable URL, so app will only download the file if current file is being played.

Comment: I think this link below is probably the answer. I am gonna test it first and let you know the result. If it can be accessible that way, then problem is solved. Link from other stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479113/13890662

Comment: Files can be accessed by anyone who has a signed URL and does not explicitly check for auth. Though it's unlikely to get one by bruteforce just like the normal URLs....

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the Authenticated URL and that was returned as error and inaccessible. I don't know what else I can do so I don't expose the URL.

Comment: @Wege so essentially `getData()` is the solution to your question?

Comment: Uhm... I think I am gonna need to test it first. If it is not working, then probably I have to use signedURL with a limited time of expiration. Sorry, I am still new here.

Comment: Security rules do restrict download as mentioned earlier in the comments and the answer as well. The same is explained in the documentation linked.

Comment: Hello @Dharmaraj, is there a way to convert Uint8List data into audio file and streamed it real-time?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482473/save-audio-stream-uint8list-data-in-file-flutter)? If you are facing issues particularly about playing the audio then it might be best to post a new question with the relevant code that you have tried and any error that you get.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68744449/15774176) :

> If you're using the FlutterFire Storage library in your app, you can
> call [getData](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getData.html) on a reference to the file to get its data. So with
> that you just need to know the path to the data, and you won't need
> the download URL in your application. Once you have the data locally,
> you can create an image out of it with: [Converting a byte array to
> image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314081/converting-a-byte-array-to-image-in-flutter)
>
> Unlike download URLs, the call to getData() is
> checked by security rules, so you'll have to ensure that the user is
> permitted to access the file.

You can also refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028697/15774176) :

> For  web apps: in the JavaScript/Web SDK using a download URL is the
> only way to get at the data, while for the native mobile SDKs we also
> have getData() and getFile() methods, which are enforced through
> security rules.
>
> Until that time, if signed URLs fit your needs
> better, you can use those. Both signed URLs and download URLs are just
> URLs that provide read-only access to the data. Signed URLs just
> expire, while download URLs don't.

For more information, you can refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/76) where a similar issue has been [discussed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/76#issuecomment-908795333).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the most completed one although it was the same as previous answer. I get all what I need along with expert answer from Frank-van-Puffelen. Thank you. Thank you too to @Dharmaraj.